# Ruby - iterating through database results and storing them in a hash

Tags: ruby

Consider the following:

```
details = Hash.new

# Example of this Hash's final look
details["team1"] = "Example"
details["team2"] = "Another team"
details["foo"]   = "Bar"
```

The way I get the names of the two teams is through:

```
teams = Match.find(1).teams
=> [#<Team id: 1, name: "England">, #<Team id: 2, name: "Australia">]
```

Now I would like to save the names of the teams into the Hash under team1 and team2. If I were using arrays I could do:

```
teams.each do |team|
  details << team.name
end
```

However, I need to do this with the Hash I have shown above. How would one go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
teams.each_with_index do |team, idx|
  id = "team#{idx + 1}"
  details[id] = team.name
end
```

Here you take the team object and make hash key out of it, and then use that key to set a value.

Comment: The problem here is that some teams may have team_ids which are not 1 or 2, so I could end up with team34 => "New Zealand", which would not work in the front-end, because it takes in team1 and team2 and displays their names when generating the details for a match-up.

Answer (score 4):

```
Hash[teams.map { |x| ["team_#{x.id}", x.name] }]
# => {"team_1"=>"England", "team_2"=>"Australia"}
```

If you want to keep id 1 and 2

```
Hash[a.map.with_index { |x,i| ["team_#{i.succ}", x.name] }]
# => {"team_1"=>"England", "team_2"=>"Australia"}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using an inject for a one liner?

```
teams.inject({}){ |details, team| details["team#{team.id}"] = team.name; details }
```

The return value will be an Array or Hashes.

Comment: How could I do this without using t.id as part of the key, and have the keys be fixed as team1 and team2 instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
{}.tap do |h|
  Match.find(1).teams.each_with_index {|t, i| h["team#{i+1}"] = t.name}
end
```

Comment: How could I do this without using t.id as part of the key, and have the keys be fixed as team1 and team2 instead?